# How do I make Clickable Text (NOT A LINK) in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, For Example:
The text will be clickable in terminal, and will lead to some type of code running when clicked.
This is not supposed to be a link.

I don't know if it matters but I'm using Visual Studio Code.

P.S: I know there probably is similar questions SOMEWHERE, but I can't find the right keywords to find it.

Comment: it is not Python problem but terminal problem. But most terminals can create clicable only links.

Comment: Eventually you may try to use some module which use `curses` to create `TUI` (Text User Interface) but it also depends on terminal: [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html), 
[windows-curses](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/windows-curses), 
[unicurses](https://github.com/unicurses/unicurses#installing-unicurses), 
[Urwid](http://urwid.org/), 
[picotui](https://github.com/pfalcon/picotui), 
[npyscreen](http://www.npcole.com/npyscreen/),  and specially 
[textual](https://github.com/Textualize/textual), 
[rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich)

Comment: Thanks furas, I'll try it out.